# Firebase: Loop on dataSnapshot executes only once

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following is my **Firebase database** graph:

[image]

There are **three** children of the root element **links**. When I execute the following loop to get all children, it returns the result for only the first child

```
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("links");
        int count=0;


        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            Log.d("Firebase","Children: "+dataSnapshot.getChildren().toString());    //This gives result for all children

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    count++;
                }
                Log.d("Firebase","Count length: "+count);     //Gives only "1"
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
```

In the above code the `count` should be 3 but it returns 1. The loop executes only once.
*However* the following line in the above code works correctly and gives results for all 3 children.

```
Log.d("Firebase","Children: "+dataSnapshot.getChildren().toString());
```

Where is the problem? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the number of children under `links`, then try the following:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d("Firebase","Children: "+dataSnapshot.getChildren().toString()); //This gives result for all children
        long childCount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

`getChildrenCount()` will return then number of direct children under `links`, in this case `3`.

Comment: I need not only count, but also data. the loop gives only first child's data

Comment: add this `Log.d("Firebase","Count length: "+count);` inside the loop

Comment: count is still 1

Comment: count is still 1

Comment: inside the loop do `String datas = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);` and log it